# How to predict the labels for the test set when using a custom Iterator in MXnet?

Tags: r, image-processing, deep-learning, mxnet

I have a big dataset (around 20GB for training and 2GB for testing) and I want to use MXnet and R. Due to lack of memory, I search for an iterator to load the training and test set by a custom iterator and I found [this](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/docs/tutorials/r/CustomIteratorTutorial.md) solution.

Now, I can train the model using the code on this page, but the problem is that if I read the test set with the save iterator as follow:

```
test.iter <- CustomCSVIter$new(iter = NULL, data.csv = "test.csv", data.shape = 480, batch.size = batch.size)
```

Then, the prediction command does not work and there is no prediction template in the [page](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/docs/tutorials/r/CustomIteratorTutorial.md);

```
preds <- predict(model, test.iter)
```

So, my specific problem is, if I build my model using the code on the page, how can I read my test set and predict its labels for the evaluation process? My test set and train set is in [this format](https://github.com/ozt-ca/tjo.hatenablog.samples/raw/master/r_samples/public_lib/jp/mnist_reproduced/short_prac_test.csv).

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works exactly as you explained. You just call predict with model and iterator:

```
preds = predict(model, test.iter)
```

The only trick here is that the predictions are displayed column-wise. By that I mean, if you take the whole [sample you are referring to](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/tutorials/r/CustomIterator.html), execute it and add the following lines:

```
test.iter <- CustomCSVIter$new(iter = NULL, data.csv = "mnist_train.csv", data.shape = 28, batch.size = batch.size)
preds = predict(model, test.iter)

preds[,1] # index of the sample to see in the column position
```

You receive:

```
 [1] 5.882561e-11 2.826923e-11 7.873914e-11 2.760162e-04 1.221306e-12 9.997239e-01 4.567645e-11 3.177564e-08 1.763889e-07 3.578671e-09
```

This show the softmax output for the 1st element of the training set. If you try to print everything by just writing `preds`, then you will see only empty values because of the RStudio print limit of 1000 - real data will have no chance to appear.

Notice that I reuse the training data for prediction. I do so, since I don't want to adjust iterator's code, which needs to be able to consume the data with and without a label in front (training and test sets). In real-world scenario you would need to adjust iterator so it would work with and without a label.